# Building a form with dynamic widgets

Tags: forms, symfony

I have 3 classes : `Category`, `Parameter` and `Product`.

- `Category` has a one-to-many relationship with `Parameters`.
- `Product` has a one-to-many relationship with `Category`.
- `Parameters` are attributes for a product  (color, weight, size,
  brand, etc.).

When I select a category and create a new product I want to create a form with these parameters.
How can I do this? Is it possible with symfony form framework? 
I hope for your help.

I trying do this something like:

```
 class ProductRepository extends EntityRepository
{

    public function getParameters()
    {
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();
        $parameters = $em->getRepository('ShopProductBundle:CatParameter')->findAll();
        $data = array();
        foreach ($parameters as $k => $value) {
            $name = $value->getId();
            $data[$name] = array("label" => $value->getName());
        }
        return $data;
    }

}
```

Form Class

```
class ProductType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name', 'text', array('label' => 'Name'));
        $data = $options['data'];
        foreach($data as $k => $item){
            $builder->add((string)$k, 'text', array('label' => $item['label']));
        }
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'shop_productbundle_categorytype';
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options){
        return array('data_class' => 'Shop\ProductBundle\Entity\Product');
    }
}
```

And create form in action:

```
$parameters = $em->getRepository('ShopProductBundle:Product')->getParameters();
$form = $this->createForm(new ProductType(), $parameters);
```

End have exception:

> Expected argument of type "Shop\ProductBundle\Entity\Product", "array"
>   given

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're getting this exception because in your controller `$parameters` is not a product.
You should build a new product, and add the parameters to it.
Also please have a look to [this article](http://sf.khepin.com/2011/08/inconsistent-behavior-of-symfony2s-form-framework/). It deals with a problem similar to yours.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you have setup data class in your form the only object you can get is it's type.

```
'data_class' => 'Shop\ProductBundle\Entity\Product'
```

The way I'm adding multiple parameters to a product entity is a collection of form items:
[How to add collection of items](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/forms/types/collection.html)

Or maybe you just want to pass parameters like this:

```
$parameters = $em->getRepository('ShopProductBundle:Product')->getParameters();
$form = $this->createForm(new ProductType(), null, $parameters);
```

Or if you would like to have an entity:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new ProductType(), new Product(), $parameters);
```